# Rails routes constraints based on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3.1. I have the following in my route:

In my model `Shop`, I have a column called `shop_type` that has either `boutique` or `saloon`. Instead of having the url:

```
http://localhost/spots/1
```

I would like to separate it by the `shop_type` to:

```
http://localhost/boutique/1
http://localhost/saloon/2
```

So I added the following to my route:

```
resources :boutique, :controller => 'shops', :constraints => { :shop_type => 'boutique' }
resources :saloon, :controller => 'shops', :constraints => { :shop_type => 'saloon' }
```

The problem with this is I can access record `ID 1` with `shop_type = boutique` with either of the URL. Ideally, it should return error when a user tries to access

```
http://localhost/saloon/1
```

But the above URL just works fine, which is not what I want.

Also, is there anyway to redirect all `shops/1` to the new URL which is by `shop_type`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, then your application is probably telling you that it really wants two separate classes, Boutique and Saloon. Can you do that? If not, why not?

Comment: If it's the right thing to do, then do the work rather than kludging around it and creating more technical debt.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its better to tell Rails directo allow urls as:

```
get "/:shop_type/:id", :to => 'shop_controller#show'
```

And in controller check if the record exist, and return :status => 404 if not:

```
@shop = Shop.where(:id => params[:id], :shop_type => params[:shop_type]).first
render :status => 404 and return if @shop.nil?
```

Note that route provided is too greedy and put it after all other routes so it will not 'eat' other request.